# DragonCash for big parks

Tags: dragonvale

I have a pretty large park, with 12 islands absolutely full of habitats. I am running out of space, so I need island 13. However, I have nowhere near that cash, so I need a good strategy to get money for large parks.

Answer (score 1):

Breed for the best ROI dragons you can.

Here is my personal top 25 list of Dragons to breed for ROI as based on the incubation time versus gold selling price.

Format: #: Name: Incubation: Sell Price

1. Wisp Dragon: 2 hours: 5,000,000
2. Nectar Dragon: 5 hours: 3,000,000
3. Iron Dragon: 4 hours: 1,150,000
4. Meadow Dragon: 9 hours: 2,500,000
5. Rust Dragon: 6 hours: 1,650,000
6. Sandstorm Dragon: 2 hours: 500,000
7. Prism Dragon: 42 hours: 10,000,000
8. Cave Dragon: 11 hours: 2,600,000
9. 2 dragons tied:

   - Ruin Dragon: 6 hours: 1,400,000
   - Nightshade Dragon: 13.5 hours: 3,150,000
10. Spark Dragon: 9.5 hours: 2,200,000
11. Root Dragon: 9 hours: 2,000,000
12. Shadow Dragon: 18 hours: 3,900,000
13. Ooze Dragon: 18.5 hours: 4,000,000
14. Luminous Dragon: 13 hours: 2,800,000
15. Crypt Dragon: 17.5 hours: 3,750,000
16. 9 dragons tied:

    - Sand Dragon: 6.5 hours: 1,300,000
    - Phantom Dragon: 8.5 hours: 1,700,000
    - Palladium Dragon: 5.5 hours: 1,100,000
    - Glare Dragon: 9.5 hours: 1,900,000
    - Flash Dragon: 6 hours: 1,200,000
    - Ember Dragon: 8 hours: 1,600,000
    - Chrome Dragon: 5 hours: 1,000,000
    - Cactus Dragon: 30 minutes: 100,000
    - Brass Dragon: 5 hours: 1,000,000

Notes: As I've said, this list is not a complete "best 25" list. It is a list taken from my own notes about Dragonvale. This is compiled from a list of 126 of the dragons I've personally bred and sold in the game. There could be more effective dragons I do not have experience with for breeding and selling for gold. But I've never seen a good listing for this in Dragonvale, which is why I started my own.

Others should feel free to update this answer if they knew more efficient dragons to breed in Dragonvale.